# Hide apps in Evie Launcher app drawer

Tags: launcher

I'm in love with the [Evie Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=is.shortcut&hl=en) however one complaint I have is that there seems no way to hide apps in the app drawer. According to [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/248374/how-to-hide-apps-from-androids-app-drawer-with-nova-launcher/) the Nova launcher has this feature but i like Evie a lot and I don't want to change my launcher.

Is there a way to do this in Evie launcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your homescreen longpress on a blank space and choose Settings. Under Customization header you would find the option "Hide Apps".

[image]